# Symfony 4 - how to set proper character encoding

Tags: oracle, symfony, character-encoding

I have problem with character encoding. I read data from Oracle DB where my charset encoding is:

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

AL32UTF8
```

In src/Kernel.php I added:

```
public function getCharset()
{
    return 'UTF-8';
}
```

In my base.html.twig is

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

In debug console is written this:

```
[debug] Warning: oci_connect(): Invalid character set name: utf8mb4
```

How to set proper value for oci_connect?

My query to DB is made by SecurityRepository.php and this is called by LoginController.php

```
//SecurityRepository.php

public function checkLoginCredentials($username, $password): array {

    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT surna, name, login FROM personal WHERE login = '" . $username . "' AND passw_coded = '" . $password . "'";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

If I write something in editor, my characers are OK, but when I read something from DB, my character set is broken. I use Symfony 4.0.4.

Comment: You should prefer bind variables for you query in order to avoid SQL-Injection. Image what happens if the password contains `'` character.

Comment: OK, I know. This is only for testing purposes. I am only learning Symfony. My main problem is with character encoding.